# Help identify minifig Pharaoh-like headdress

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

Recently found this minifig headdress in a bag with mixed LEGO and analogs. Not sure if it belongs to LEGO, but quality is great and it perfectly fits minifigure head. The sets in bag was belong to periods from 1994 to 2000 and from 2011 to 2017.

I tried Google Lens. Tried to search it in Adventurers, Pharaoh Quest, Castle, Prince of Persia, Pirates, Pirates of the Caribbean and collectible minifigs serieses, but have not found any thing similar to it.

Any suggestions of sets or even serieses is appreciated.

[image: Lego-compatible headdress]

[image: Lego-compatible headdress]

Minifigure bellow is from 2021 creator castle is just for example of how it looks.

[image: Lego-compatible headdress]

[image: Lego-compatible headdress]

Comment: If someone has the full BrickLink catalog handy, it would probably be easy to filter on Minifigure, Headgear and sort by weight. That thing is **huge**. I don't personally recognize it as a Lego piece, and I searched that category by release year back a while, and nothing seemed to match.

Comment: Do you find any numbers or other markings on it (on the inside of the cap eg.) ?

Comment: Only number i found is "2" at the bottom of the cap. No markings.

Comment: I scanned through bricklink's black headgear, no hits. Suspecting a clone brand. Perhaps there's a theme to the clone sets in OP's bags that can help narrow down the search?

Comment: Thanks for the fun challenge, Ivan.  Can you add any info about the quality of the plastic?  Are there any seams you can see or feel?

Comment: I don't have any of clone-brands pieces from that bag left (only LEGO's and the ones I'm not sure about, like that one). I remember, there was a classic pirate clone set, something like western themed set and a lot of modern warfare sets (few tank's and truck, I guess). Plastic quality is very good, I would say it's LEGO quality or very close to it. There is one seam at the back of the headpiece, I added photo to OP.

Comment: I think the sole small number 2 printed inside is a good indication this is off brand. I just inspected a minifig headwear (police mans hat) and in the case of Lego, there's much more printed inside (at least two numbers and a  copyright notice) around the stud recess...

Comment: That's almost always true today, but historically, Lego has had a... variety... of methods they used to mark pieces like this. I'm fairly sure I've seen a bare number like that in pieces that were definitely Lego brand.

Comment: I can confirm that - I have several headgear in my collection that just have a single digit number (likely the mould id) on them. These are mostly from the late eighties, early nineties.

Answer (score 9):

This looks to be a custom creation by [BrickTW](http://thebrickblogger.com/2011/04/lego-customizer-bricktw-overview/). They are apparently no longer in operation though (closed down early 2020).

Found through google image search with keywords "lego compatible headdress". This search turned up this element sold under the name ["BrickTW - Nanman Priests Headdress" at Firestarter Toys](https://www.firestartoys.com/products/bricktw---nanman-priest-headdress---light-blueish-gray.html) (albeit not available in black).

[image: I would include the image from that link in this answer, but am not sure whether that would fall under fair use or not. If someone knows of a legal way to do that, please feel free to edit.]

Comment: Looks like it is, thank you! It's a pity that this is not from some set, this part is very unusual.

Comment: Great find! My searches for "minifigure headdress" yielded less useful results. I've put in a link to the image that's on their website, but that link may go bad, so I'll save a copy locally just in case. I would prefer a BrickTW image directly, but haven't found that either.

Comment: @RSchulz : thanks for the edit - I've been looking unsuccessfully for an image closer to the source. I'll keep my eyes open, but am not hopeful.

Comment: Also available in some shade of [Brown/Tan](https://www.firestartoys.com/products/bricktw---nanman-priest-headdress---dark-tan.html)